# Leaflet / Mapbox marine traffic density Map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, data-visualization, mapbox, data-analysis

I am currently making a marine traffic tool using Leaftlet and Mapbox. For that, I have a huge amount of AIS Data that I converted in GeoJSON file. The GeoJSON file is a list of "LineString" defining each ship's trajectories like this :

```
{
  "features": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          [-4.013451666666667, 5.276998333333333, 1442197395],
          ...
        ],
        "type": "LineString"
      },
      "properties": {
        "mmsi": "228326800",
        "color": "#1CE6FF",
        "type": "aht_tug_supply"
      },
      "type": "Feature"
    }
  ],
  "type": "FeatureCollection"
}
```

And it is working pretty well if I want to show each ship independently. But now, I would like to make a "heat" map of the area a bit like this :
[MarineTraffic.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XO1st.png)

So my question is : How to imitate a map like this one? Usually, heat maps are for points not segments. (cf. [Leaftlet.heat](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat))

If you have some books / references to help me in my data visualisation work, it would be perfect!

Comment: checkout kepler.gl- an open source data vis tool uber just released. this specific example seems relevant: http://kepler.gl/#/demo/ukcommute

Comment: Ok, thanks for your link, it seems really interesting. Unfortunately, my data are confidential and I can't upload them directly in a third-party tool. But the layers are pretty interesting, and I will try them with a little part of the data. Thanks again!

Comment: Yup! And kepler is entirely client side so uploading your data shouldn't send it to their server (this is stated where you upload data: "*Kepler.gl is a client-side application with no server backend. Data lives only on your machine/browser. No information or map data is sent to any server.")

Comment: Oh! Thank you for the precision. I will definitely try it so!